# CSS PostStylus Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, stylus, autoprefixer

Using CSS autoprefixer seaneking/poststylus for webpack 4.
As in manual adding plugin in config:

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      stylus: {
        use: [poststylus([ 'autoprefixer', 'rucksack-css' ])]
      }
    }
  })
]
```

And importing stylus-file from js-file, so styles should be included in js-file

```js
import css from './app.styl';
```

Package goes without errors, but there are no autoprefixes in result file.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use this package instead: https://github.com/jescalan/autoprefixer-stylus

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-stylus');

{
  test: /\.styl$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
    },
    {
      loader: 'stylus-loader', // compiles Stylus to CSS
      options: {
        use: [
          autoprefixer(),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
},
```